# Can't find 'com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService'

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

When building a Signed APK from an ionic Cordova project I got the below warnings.

```
com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushInstanceIDListenerService: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService


com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushInstanceIDListenerService: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService
```

Seems **InstanceIDListenerService** class was deprecated as of Google APIs for Android.

cordova-plugin-mfp: 8.0

cordova-plugin-mfp-push: 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Proguard rules:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.measurement.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.iid.**
```